# Box-shadow shows around block not around text when applying it to h2

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
    <h2>Set RSVP & Check in</h2>
    <p>
        Set RSVP to remind all events you plan to go.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 156px;
}

.div1 h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 black;
}
```

And border appears like "table border" not the border on text:

http://screencast.com/t/OrFfBL9MK

Comment: You're confusing `box-shadow` with `text-shadow`, shown in the answer below. Also, borders don't apply to text. As of now, there is no CSS for text border/stroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing box-shadow with text-shadow.

Try this:

```
.div1 h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px 0px;
}
```